# map multiple input element to a single output response element as comma separated

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to map multiple input which are at same level in XSD to a target element as comma seperated values. can this is doable in XSLT 1.0

**Input structure**

```
<Errors>
<error>
<errorcode>code</errorcode>
<errortype>type</errortype>
<paramater1>error1</paramater1>
<paramater2>error2</paramater2>
<paramater3/>error3</paramater3>
<paramater4/>error4</paramater4>
<error>
<Errors>
```

**Output**

```
<output>error1,error2,error3,error4</output>
```

Please note - other element like errorcode,errortype should remain same.. I am using those in other mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using these templates :

```
<xsl:template match="error">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- apply identity transform for child elements which name doesn't start with 'parameter' -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(starts-with(name(), 'paramater'))]"/>

        <!-- output comma-separated value from child elements which name start with 'parameter' -->
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'paramater')]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```